# In Bot Framework, conversation.sendAsync() is no longer available in v3, what is an alternative to it, to call an IDialog method in reply to the user?

Tags: botframework

I am trying to replicate the Sandwich Bot provided in the documentation. However, version 3 of the Bot Builder does not support that example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about the Node.js version of the Bot Builder because there has been no change in the C# version.

New dialogs can be started using `bot.dialog` and `session.beginDialog`:

```
bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session) {
        session.beginDialog('/askName');
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.send('Hello %s!', results.response);
    }
]);
bot.dialog('/askName', [
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi! What is your name?');
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.endDialogWithResult(results);
    }
]);
```